# Can't Load Tagger Model in Stanford CoreNLP Java API

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I had been working with the Stanford CoreNLP API version 4.0.0 in java. However, recently I upgraded to version 4.1.0 and am having problems using the "pos" annotator. Specifically, I am not able to load the tagger model. I have confirmed that the models jar is in my class path and that I do not have multiple versions of the CoreNLP in my class path. I have also extracted the models jar file and confirmed that the pos-tagger is included. From what I can find, it appears that the pos-tagger is the only model that can't be accessed. For one last try, I dowloaded the english model jar and tried to replace the models jar with this new download. This did not work. Here are the two errors I am getting:

```
edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:801)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:322)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:275)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:85)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:73)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.posTagger(AnnotatorImplementations.java:68)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$5(StanfordCoreNLP.java:527)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$32(StanfordCoreNLP.java:608)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:126)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:149)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:253)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:194)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:190)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:482)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:798)
    ... 44 more
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The model should be available in the stanford-corenlp-4.1.0-models.jar. It is not in the English models jar. Make sure to have that jar in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: We've recently changed the path name for that model, so this error suggests you have an outdated models jar somewhere. Also, how are you setting CLASSPATH, and how are you executing code?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I thought I removed old jars from the CLASSPATH, but I must have not done so. Everything is working now. Very helpful library, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about how your code works.

Comment: Is there a Gradle version of including the models?

Answer (score 0):

Heads up, if you are using gradle you will want to do something along these lines

```
implementation("edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:4.1.0:models")
```